# Scrapy : Is it possible to crawl different websites by using url extension?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a `start_url` named `www.example.edu`

First I would like to start crawling websites at 0 depth with similar extension .

Second i want to stop the spider from crawling when it has crawled a number of 20 websites for example .

Are these two restrictions possible to be achieved?

Suppose i have this code :

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spiderz'
    allowed_domains = ['berkeley.edu']
    start_urls = ['http://www.berkeley.edu/',]
```

I wonder if it's possible to crawl after the `start_url` ,a random domain with same extension for example phoenix.edu then columbia.edu using only the **.edu** as a rule pattern.

I am interested only about the domain names .

I want to collect 20 random domain names with .edu extension

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a specific example and some code you have so far? This might help us to have a clear picture and to better help. Thanks.